# load a video into a div when clicking a image link

Tags: jquery, html, video

hope someone can help.

I am trying to create a page where you have 3 thumbnail images of stills form a video. When you click on the image link, a video should load into a large div above the thumbnails.

I am stuck on loading the actual video into the large div, at the moment it opens in a new tab (using a youtube video as an example).

Can anyone suggest a method of creating this?

Example of code:

jQuery:

```
 $(".video-1, .video-2, .video-3").on("click", function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $(".video_main iframe").prop("src", $(event.currentTarget).attr("href"));
        });
```

html

```
<div class="video_main">
 <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="video/video-1.mp4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div class="video_wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li class="video_thumbnail"><a href="video/video-1.mp4" class="video-1" title=""><img src="images/videoPlayer-thumbnail-1.jpg" alt=""/></a></li>
        <li class="video_thumbnail"><a href="video/video-2.mp4" class="video-2" title=""><img src="images/videoPlayer-thumbnail-2.jpg" alt=""/></a></li>
        <li class="video_thumbnail"><a href="video/video-3.mp4" class="video-3" title=""><img src="images/videoPlayer-thumbnail-3.jpg" alt=""/></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you checked the javascript code? I think it should be: `$(".video-1, .video-2, .video-3").click(function(){`

Comment: Awgh thats an error while typing it in here, sorry! It is correct in my file :) Seems to load just not in my main_video class div! Tried a local file and it opens in a huge screen rather than inside the div :/

Comment: _"wgh thats an error while typing it in here, sorry!"_ what I though :) . I think I can't be so helpful here...I would try to set a jsfiddle up in order to make easy to figure out what your problem is to the other users.

Answer (score 1):

This would be the video case:

```
<div class="video_case">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/WY32nnKrB70" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

The thumbnails:

```
<div class="video_wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li class="video_thumbnail"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/WY32nnKrB70" class="video-1" title=""><img src="images/videoPlayer-thumbnail-1.jpg" alt=""/></a></li>
        <li class="video_thumbnail"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0" class="video-2" title=""><img src="images/videoPlayer-thumbnail-2.jpg" alt=""/></a></li>
        <li class="video_thumbnail"><a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0" class="video-3" title=""><img src="images/videoPlayer-thumbnail-3.jpg" alt=""/></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And your js:

```
$(".video-1, .video-2, .video-3").on("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(".video_case iframe").prop("src", $(event.currentTarget).attr("href"));
});
```

Comment: This is great, thank you, this is what i was trying to get across :) only issue is that when i click a thumbnail into the div it opens in fulls creen mode rather within the div. I will update my code as i have used examples with local files.

Comment: Np. Try using the url from the "embed" section in Youtube. Here's a working version of it for you http://jsfiddle.net/6kL4K/.

Comment: Your snippet works but when applied to my files it still plays fullscreen! Changed browsers and even copied exact code from the snippet. I have disabled my css files incase this was ignoring anything, this is so strange!

Comment: Change the width and height on your iframe. I was using width="560" height="315" in my example. Having 100%x100% will make it full screen.

Comment: No still when you click on thumbnail it doesnt load in the div just as  'http://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0' rather than the webpage in the main video div- this is so strange!

Comment: Make sure you're using the embed url code. In http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=oHg5SJYRHA0, see the &v=VIDEOID, grab that snippet and use http://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEOID.

Comment: yeah, make sure i used the embed code, also tried local files and when thumbnail clicked its taking me to the file location rather than the websiteurl if this makes sense! Works fine in your snippet and even created a new file on localhost and still does the same.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30129/discussion-between-jmparsons-and-user2212564)

Comment: @JMParsons can i set the default thumbnail in the video_wrapper div, if yes how? thanks

Comment: people, you all have been rickroll'd twice, and none saying a word about it? :-) btw, I also noticed that just once (first execution) the video opened fullscreen, then it started to open in the right div...

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need here is something like this:

```
<embed
width="420" height="345"
src="http://www.youtube.com/v/XGSy3_Czz8k"
type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
</embed>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp

You also can take a look at the `<video>` tag that HTML5 introduces.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: It's more changing the video in the main div when each image link is clicked, not to embed , i think it has something to do with the jQuery function? Thanks though!