# click image to display video

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some thumbnail images in a gallery, when the user clicks them I want it to display a video in a preview box. I already have the javascript set up to display images in the preview box as there are two sections in my gallery- images and videos.

Would I just copy the function in javascript for the images for the videos as well? I know I will need to imbed the videos as well but I'm not sure where to put them in the HTML, as I only want them to display in the preview box when the thumbnail image has been clicked.

NOTE:
I tried to put this in a fiddle but its difficult to do with broken image links.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
<div id="display"><img id="displayimg"></div>



 <div class="select">
    <div class="imagesection">
        <div class="galleryrow">
            <img id="selectimg" src="../assets/images/gallery/image1.png" onclick='javascript:display(this)'>
            <img id="selectimg" src="../assets/images/gallery/image2.png" onclick='javascript:display(this)'>
            <img id="selectimg" src="../assets/images/gallery/image3.png" onclick='javascript:display(this)'>
        </div>

        <div class="galleryrow">
            <img id="selectimg" src="../assets/images/gallery/image4.png" onclick='javascript:display(this)'>   
            <img id="selectimg" src="../assets/images/gallery/image5.png" onclick='javascript:display(this)'>
            <img id="selectimg" src="../assets/images/gallery/image6.png" onclick='javascript:display(this)'>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="videosection">
        <div class="galleryrow">
            <img id="selectimg" src="../assets/images/gallery/video1.png" onclick='javascript:display(this)'>
            <img id="selectimg" src="../assets/images/gallery/video2.png" onclick='javascript:display(this)'>
            <img id="selectimg" src="../assets/images/gallery/video3.png" onclick='javascript:display(this)'>
        </div>

        <div class="galleryrow">
            <img id="selectimg" src="../assets/images/gallery/video4.png" onclick='javascript:display(this)'>
            <img id="selectimg" src="../assets/images/gallery/video5.png" onclick='javascript:display(this)'>
            <img id="selectimg" src="../assets/images/gallery/video6.png" onclick='javascript:display(this)'>
        </div>
    </div>

<!--END OF SELECT-->
</div>
```

CSS

```
    #display{
    margin: 0 auto;
    height:468px;
    width:627px;
    padding-top:37px;
}

#display img{
    height:100%;
    width:100%; 
}

.select{
    padding-top:78px;

}

.select img{
    width:146px;
}

.galleryrow {
    display:block;
}

.videosection {
    float:left;
    margin-left:30px;
}

.imagesection {
    float:left;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function display(imgElement){
    document.getElementById('displayimg').setAttribute('src',imgElement.getAttribute('src'));
}
```

Comment: Is it a youtube video or just a video you are going to host yourself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [load a video into a div when clicking a image link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607893/load-a-video-into-a-div-when-clicking-a-image-link)

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

1. Place `<a href>` around each `<img>` tag
2. Set a target iframe for the video
3. Name the iframe that is the target

For example:

```
<iframe name="iframe1" class="myClass"></iframe>
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/myVideo1" target="iframe1"><img id="selectimg" src="../assets/images/gallery/image1.png"></a>
```

Your video should play in the iframe set by the target

By the way, you will have some html errors (use a validator to track these) if you keep the same id for each image...I would come up with a consistent naming system. For example, each image is successively numbered to match the file name. Let id="selectimg1" correspond to image1.png, id="selectimage2" correspond to image2.png, etc.

Comment: so you are suggesting this as an alternative to the javascript?

Comment: I am looking for a javascript solution sorry